# how to pass each id of json data from one ajax call to another using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to get data from food2fork api, in this two api's is there to get the data. One for recipe search and another for ingredients details.I am trying to fetch each id's and pass it to another ajax call. So far my code shown below:

```
http://food2fork.com/api/search?key=7508d614a766c7768131b60ef99a3f52&q=pizza
http://food2fork.com/api/get?key=7508d614a766c7768131b60ef99a3f52&rId=35128
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var id, b, c, temp;
    $("#button1").click(function() {
        var food = $("#food").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "https://mindapp-pulpy.rhcloud.com/AuthXmlPulpy",
            data: {
                appid: 'MPAPP_1060',
                p1: food
            },
            //global:false,
            //async:false,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#display1").hide();
                $(data).find("root").each(function() {
                    id = $(this).find("rid").text(); //recipe-id
                    b = $(this).find("img").text(); //image-url
                    c = $(this).find("title").text(); //title
                    console.log(id);
                    $("#disimg").append('<div class="col-md-4"><div class="panel panel-info"><div class="panel-heading myshow"><strong>' + c + '</strong></div><div class="panel-body"><img class= "img-responsive thumbnail" src="' + b + '" style="height:150px;width:200px;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mine"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span> Details..</button></div></div></div>');

                    $('.myshow').on('click', +c, function(event) {
                        if (event.handled !== true) {
                            listObject.itemID = id;
                            var currentID = listObject.itemID;
                            window.sessionStorage.setItem('parentId', currentID);
                            console.log(currentID + 'recipeid');
                            event.handled = true;
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                });
            }, //success
            beforeSend: function() {
                // Code to display spinner
                $("#disimg").empty();
                $(".loader").show();
            },
            complete: function() {
                // Code to hide spinner.
                $(".loader").hide();
            },
            error: function(request, error) {
                $("#display1").hide();
                $("#mydisplay").html('<center><h1> OOPS! </strong> Network error, Data not found..</center></h1>');
            }
        }); //ajax ends
        var parentId = sessionStorage.getItem('parentId');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://mindapp-pulpy.rhcloud.com/AuthXmlPulpy",
            data: {
                appid: 'MPAPP_1065',
                p1: parentId
            },
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                xmlParser(xml);
            }
        });

        function xmlParser(xml) {
            //var parentId=sessionStorage.getItem('parentId');
            $(xml).find("root").each(function() {
                var d = $(this).find("recid").text();
                var desc = $(this).find("indg").text();
                console.log(desc);
                //$("#details").append('desc:'+ desc +'<br>');
            });
        }
    });
}); //document
```

It just takes the last `recipe_id`, Where i went wrong? can you please help me

Comment: Please format your so that it's readable (which includes proper indentation). That's the least you can do if you expect others to have a look at your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is expected because of the behavior of closure,

wrap the inner handler into another closure like this would solve the issue

```
(function (id) {
    $('.myshow').on('click', +c, function (event) {
        if (event.handled !== true) {
            listObject.itemID = id;
            var currentID = listObject.itemID;
            window.sessionStorage.setItem('parentId', currentID);
            console.log(currentID + 'recipeid');
            event.handled = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
})(id);
```

look at the [common mistake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake)

In your case the on click handler will be executed later point in time, and at that moment the value of the `id` would be the last element of the `each` loop.

the soulutin would work since it creates another private clousure and having separate `id` values for each.

Comment: I have changed as per your coding snippet above, the id issue has solved now then how can i assign each id to parentId variable to pass the second api.(eg..,var parentId=sessionStorage.getItem('id');) where i can put the id.